# How to attach a function to a form element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to attach a function to an input element in the javascript file but it is not working as i want please suggest the correct syntax or any other solution also i don't want use inline html method like `<input type="text" id="name" onfocus="hello()">`. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rayees123/xvm5qLpt/),

```js
document.getElementById("name").onfocus = hello();
function hello () {
    alert("hello");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name">
```

I want the function to be executed when the input element gets focus but here the function is executing immediately the page loading completes. Please i want pure javascript no jquery.

Comment: Answer is correct Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function hello () {
    alert("hello");
}
document.getElementById("name").onfocus = hello;
```

Comment: It is not working when i have to pass any arguments like .onfocus=hello("name");

Comment: then you need: `.onfocus = function() { hello("name") };`

Answer (score 3):

attach the event listener instead

```js
  document.getElementById("name").addEventListener("focus", function(){
   alert('Hello')
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name">
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok firstly, the function hello needs to be defined **before** you define it as the function to be used for the event.

Secondly, you need to remove the brackets from the function name when you set it as the onfocus function. You're giving a reference to the function, to be used later, not executing it there and then.

Therefore this should work:

`function hello () {
    alert("hello");
}
document.getElementById("name").onfocus = hello;`

Comment: Then how can i  pass arguments like .onfocus=hello("name");

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What are you trying to achieve (in reality?). I assume you don't actually want to pop up an alert box when the focus is gained?

Comment: Actually i have written a script to validate forms where i am using inline html method for attaching the functions like onsubmit="CheckForm("form")" and it works perfectly, but i want to remove that inline html method and i want attach function in the external javascript file to form elements not in the html file.

Comment: ok, so say you assign the CheckForm function (with no parameters) to the onsubmit event of a `<form>` element. Once you run the function, the built-in javascript `this` keyword will represent the form element that the event is triggered from. So you don't need to pass it, it's there already.

Comment: The only thing you can pass when handling an JS event is the event itself. See here: http://javascript.info/tutorial/obtaining-event-object

Comment: But i need the the parameter to perform some operations inside the CheckForm() function.

Comment: what are you passing in the parameter exactly? in your example it looked like you were just passing the id of the form. As I already mentioned, you get get the form element by referencing `this` inside the function

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("name").addEventListener("focus", function(){alert('test')}, false);
```